# how to avoid the authentication process of the login control if i'm aware of the login cridentials?

Tags: asp.net, login-control, web-to-winforms

I developed one web site. And called the web site through windows form application with the help of web browser control. I used login control from asp.net in the web site for login process.

I want to avoid the authentication process of login control when web site is called from the windows forms application.

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can send some encrypted key, like an api key that google/facebook uses.
This key can match with your login/salt or anythin you like

Comment: can u provide some document related to what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`WebBrowser.Navigate(string, string, byte[], string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161355.aspx) method to make your request, passing in the credentials either as POST data, or as supplementary HTTP headers. For example (with a supplementary header):

```
var headers = "X-Credentials: CREDENTIALS_HERE";

browserControl.Navigate("http://www.myserver.com/Page.aspx", "", null, headers);
```

NOTE: I'm not sure if you need to pass in `null` or an emptry `byte[]` for the 3rd parameter.

Your page can then read the data from the additional header(s) and use that to authenticate the request, rather than requiring your user go through the login process.